# Old sci-fi or fantasy short story about a purple chemical (maybe in the rain) falling from the sky

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for a short story for a friend. They're not sure what the plot is, but my friend is looking for an old sci-fi story about a purple chemical (maybe in the rain) falling from the sky. The chemical either killed people or put them into a coma/sleep, and the main character had to travel to someone else's house to find a cure for it. Everyone else on Earth was either asleep or dead, but by the end they were revived. If this sounds familiar, please let me know! Thanks in advance! :] Edit: They've clarified that they remember it being published from around 1890-1910, so not true sci-fi but in a similar vein. Edit 2: Thank you to Winchell Chung--it was The Poison Belt!

Comment: When you say "old," do you mean old as in 2000, old as in 1980, or old as in 1960...?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure. They say they think that it's "pre-Bradbury", but aren't sure.

Comment: You may have found the story that inspired Prince....

Comment: The Poison Belt by Arthur Conan Doyle has the world rendered unconscious by gas falling from space, but nothing else fits the description

Comment: @user14111 There's enough similarity, especially in subject and time-frame that it's probably worth posting that as an answer.

Comment: @WinchellChung If you post your answer as an Answer rather than as a comment on the question, the poster can mark it as the accepted Answer, and you can get credit for it.